# LinuxMint - `who`, `w` and `last` don't report terminal-emulators anylonger

Tags: logs, xterm, terminal-emulator, last, who

I'm running an up-to-date version of LinuxMint (an Ubuntu-fork), and I've noticed that `who`, `w` and `last` have all stopped registering activity on terminal-emulators (like `xterm`) - eg. if you open a terminal under X.  The only thing registered, is that the WindowManager/DesktopEnviroment is runnung on a VirtualTerminal (eg. */dev/tty7* or */dev/tty8*).

If I log-in to one of the VirtualTerminals on F1-F6 (*/dev/tty1-6*), that is registered.  Also if I log-in with `ssh` in a terminal-emulator under X.  Multiple "terminals" made with `screen` are also registered (even when used in a terminal-emulator under X)

But just opening a terminal-emulator (and running programs in it) are no longer noticed.

AFAIK, users currently logged-in are registered in */var/run/utmp*, while previous log-ins (and boots) are logged in */var/log/wtmp* - and these files are used by `who`, `w` and `last`.

So for some reason, opening a terminal-emulator in X is no-longer registered in these logs.  While there are some sense in this (I'm not actually logging-in), I would much preferred that it was logged... not at least since I then could use `w` to see what I'm doing in various shells.

So is there a way to turn back on the logging of terminal-emulators?  Preferably so that also how long they stayed open was also registered...

Comment: You tagged the question with `xterm`. I don't know what happens under `xterm` and how to re-enable utmp logging. In case you use `gnome-terminal` or other `vte`-based emulator, utmp logging has been removed from them, see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046.

Comment: @egmont Thanks for the suggestion.  I tagged it `xterm` mostly because it is the "standard" terminal-emulator.

Answer (score 4):

UPDATED: Did some research.

The terminal emulator needs to be told to write a log entry into `/var/log/utmp`.  With `xterm`, this is done by starting `xterm` with `-ut` or by setting the `Xterm*utmpInhibit` resource to `false` (which is the default).

This is different for `gnome-terminal`, obviously.  In fact, it seems as if `gnome-terminal` is dropping `utmp` support completely: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=747046

Summary of that bug report: Developers want to remove `utmp` support completely, and as far as I understand, they did (in 2015).

Comment: Nope. Login shell and interactive shell are independent concepts. And they have no relation to utmp logging either, since bash cannot do such logging. It's usually the terminal emulator that does utmp logging.

Comment: So what else could explain this behavior? I also am very curious about this.